# Boxing to Object type to avoid compilation failure

Tags: java, java-7, autoboxing

Consider the following code

```
public class Foo
{

  int value;
  public Foo (final String str, Object ... bug)
  {
    System.out.println ("Should work! 1");
  }

  public Foo (final String str, final int value, Object ... bug)
  {
     this.value = value;
    System.out.println ("Should work! 2");
  }

  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Foo f = new Foo ("Foo", 3); //Line 14
    System.out.println(f.value);
  }
}
```

When I was using jdk-1.6.x I was successfully able to compile it.
but upon upgrading to jdk-1.7 it gives me error :

`Foo.java:18: error: reference to Foo is ambiguous, both constructor Foo(String,Object...) in Foo and constructor Foo(String,int,Object...) in Foo match
    Foo f = new Foo ("Foo", 3); //Line 14`

So to avoid this error I changed second Ctor to

```
  public Foo (final String str, final Integer value, Object ... bug)
  {
     this.value = value;
    System.out.println ("Should work! 2");
  }
```

So that it can autobox to Integer and skip the compilation error.

Few question :
1) Is it a good practise ? If not then is there other way ?
2) Why java developer would have taken the decision to give error instead of allowing it ?

Comment: If it works on 1.6 . It must not have to give error on 1.7.

Comment: I've verified that it does not work on 1.7 like the OP claims.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design and a known area of incompatibility between Java 6 and Java 7 because the overload-resolution algorithm was fixed in Java 7. In Java 5 and 6, the following code would not compile:

```
class Test {
    void foo(int... i) {}
    void foo(double... d) {}

    void test() {
       foo(1,2,3);
    }
}
```

The compiler would complain that the calls were ambiguous. But this isn't true because `double` is more general than `int` and therefore `int` is the most-specific option in this case.

However this fix resulted in an incompatibility (look at the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7); search for "varargs"). The upshot is that you cannot choose the most-specific method when you have `int` and `Object` because neither is a subtype of the other. So this shouldn't compile. However, you can use `Integer`, because `Integer` is a subtype of `Object` and in this case it is the most-specific option and so the compiler can choose that.

Pertinent section from the release notes:

> While the `javac` compiler accepts more code than it did prior to JDK 7, this fix also results in a slight source incompatibility in the following case:

```
class Test {
    void foo(int... i) {}
    void foo(Object... o) {}

    void test() {
       foo(1,2,3);
    }
}
```

> This code compiles in JDK 6 (the most specific method is `foo(int...)`). This code does not compile under JDK 7. As per [15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), it is not possible to choose between `foo(int...)` and `foo(Object...)` as neither `int` is a subtype of `Object`, nor `Object` is a subtype of `int`. This program should be disallowed (in fact, it should never have been allowed in the first place).

> Nature of Incompatibility: behavioral and source

> RFE: [6199075](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6199075)

Answer (score 1):

> Why java developer would have taken the decision to give error instead of allowing it ?

The error occurs due to a change in the way var-args are [perceived in JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html).

> 1) Is it a good practise ? If not then is there other way ?

While you can use Integers to get around the problem, the class Foo originally had an int as its member variable and I'd keep it that way. Note that `Integer value;` can now accept null. Check for null in your code and use `value.intValue()` to assign the value to the member variable.

Uncaught NPEs and performance are big nuisances with autoboxing / unboxing.

Comment: But I guess null will be translated as 0. So unless my default value is other than 0, I should be careful.

Comment: Null is not translated to 0. It is translated to a NPE at runtime.